# insert method is overwriting what is in the cart and not adding to it

Tags: codeigniter, cart

```
if($this->input->post('tambah')){
   $kode = $this->input->post('kode');
   $jumlah = $this->input->post('jumlah');
   $hjual = $this->input->post('hjual');
   $nama = $this->input->post('nama');
   $exp = $this->input->post('tglexp');
   $hpp = $this->input->post('hpp');
   $temp_stok = $this->input->post('temp_stok');
   $diskon = $this->input->post('diskon');
  $cart = array(
       'id'      => $kode,
       'qty'     => $jumlah,
       'price'   => $hjual,
       'name'    => $nama,
       'options' => array('exp' => $exp, 'hpp' => $hpp, 
                  'temp_stok' => $temp_stok , 'diskon'=>$diskon ));

   $this->cart->insert($cart);

   header('location:'.base_url().'penjualan/load_input_barang_eceran');
   }
```

I cant seem to add any more items and the latest one I add replaces the existing one.
I had like this in another controller but strangely can insert and not overwriting

Comment: Sorry I answered prematurely and removed my answer...the code looks ok.  Are the '`id'=>$kode` values unique?

Comment: @Dan only contain numbers which makes me confused is that the code is the result of copy and paste the other controller I've adjusted but get different results

Comment: Don't know, but if I were you I would look at the _sessions table in your db to see what data is being entered.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this.

It was non alphanumerics in the product code which caused the whole cart to behave strangely.

Try just having aaa123 etc as codes to test this

Comment: if there is a problem if I have two controllers are like that? because the other one works while this does not work

Comment: It's the product strings not the controller I found.  The cart class works fine until it gets odd characters...